# Sandbox Refresh - Sites configuration

Tags: refresh

Do Sandbox refreshes wipe away Site(communities) configurations on the Sandbox and replace them with the production settings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It does. 
As per the definition Sandbox is the Copy of the Production and whatever metadata and data configuration exist over there will be copied into Sandbox, depends on your sandbox type.